# overflow menu has no background

Tags: android, android-button, android-menu

[image]

For some reason, the background tiles for the options are not showing when I click the overflow button at the bottom of the screen.

I have gone over the code, but I can't find anything that would cause such a thing. There is basically no background behind the text. If I change the background colour to black then the text won't be seen.

Here is all the code related to the menu options:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {        
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.new_game:               
            gameView.startNewGame();                
            return true;
        case R.id.stats:
            return true;
        case R.id.help:
            gameInfo.show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}
```

Also according to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13689548/1973276, the way to get the overflow button to show at the bottom is to set the tarketSDKVersion to 13. That is what I did to get it to appear at the bottom of the screen, but since that reply was 2 years ago, SDK 13 has long be replaced and it is recommended to use the latest SDK. Is there a better way in placing the overflow button in the bottom bar?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Is there a better way in placing the overflow button in the bottom bar?" -- the better way is to not have it there at all. The "menu button of shame" is something to be avoided, as it suggests to users that your app is not being maintained. If you do not want the action bar, that's fine, but you should build your own menu system as part of your own UI, the way that games do. As to why you are not getting the proper background, that's probably something coming from a custom theme that you specified in the manifest.

Comment: You know what, You are absolutely right. After trying to work with what I have and trying to stick with the overflow button, I figured its not worth it. I would look a lot nicer if I build my own menu. Turn your comment into an answer and I will accept it.