# How do I add the options to the button dock?

Tags: android, settings

In android I am trying to get it so that the three dots appear next to the multi task button. Does anyone know how to do this? Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you Speaking about `overflow menu`?

Comment: I think so but I would like it to be at the bottom of the screen where the other buttons are (Back, Home, and the muli-task).

Comment: Have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689272/android-overflow-menu-in-bottom-bar ?